# How to store char buffer in a std::queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, queue, buffer

I have a udp client which has 2 threads.
The data which is received from socket is put into a queue which is processed by the second thread.

What is the proper way to do this?
Is this correct?

**Case 1**

```
char* buffer = new char[1024];
Receive the socket data in buffer
Lock mutex
_queue.push_back(buffer)
signal the waiting thread
Unlock mutex

//In second thread
while(1)
    while(queue not empty)
        Lock mutex
        const char* buf = _queue.front()
        _queue.pop();
        Unlock mutex
        ...
        Some strtok actions on buf **(This is causing crash)**
        ...
        delete[] buf    //Removing this line removes crash
    conditional wait
```

Comment: Just remove the instruction to delete the pointer and it should be fine.  The pop returns the value and removes it from the queue :)  The reason for the crash is most likely because you are trying to delete something which doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @GMasucci Yes, I removed it and crash is gone. But valgrind is report memory leak for the same. Who will free the buffer?

Comment: nearly:)  a sscce is a small version of your code which employs the same instructions and exactly replicates your error/issue

Comment: I have provided the relevant parts where I am dealing with the buffer.

Comment: if this is C++ and the inter-thread op is internal to your program (does not require C interface), might I suggest using a queue of managed memory, such as vector<char> or string?

Comment: to me it looks like your external interface ends at receiving the socket data. You can then wrap that in a managed object and send that along to the other thread for a more robust system

Comment: Can you show me an example? You mean I have to use `vector<char>` which has 1024 characters and put this vector inside the queue?

Comment: vector<char> buffer(1024, 0); // zero-construct buffer

Comment: queue<vector<char>> _queue;

Comment: yes, exactly. Then your news/deletes are all gone

Comment: Keep in mind that in this multithreaded environment, I am not sure about your thread-local storage or how you pass this queue, but this should work given what I can tell from the small amount of code

Comment: queue is a global variable shared by both the threads.

Comment: you can use &buffer[0] or buffer.data() to access the pointer to the buffer itself for receiving the data from the socket

Comment: Two things - thread-safe access to the std::queue, and how does the consumer thread know that there is something in the queue to pop?

Comment: @MartinJames Added more code/algorithm used

Comment: once you convert your char * to std::string, use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c/55680 to dump your use of strtok (which I find ugly due to its manipulation of the input string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C++ containers are not thread safe. You need to put some kind of blocking around the accesses to the queue, otherwise it's quite possible that `front()` is returning an invalid pointer.

Comment: That, and I don't see any signal that the consumer thread waits on to ensure that there is something in the queue to pop?

Comment: @MartinJames I was assuming there is some code to do that but it wasn't shared with us. Good point though.

Comment: @MarkRansom `front()` & `pop()` is called inside a `while` which checks that queue is not empty and it is also mutex protected to avoid simultaneous `push` and `pop`

Comment: @cppcoder did it not occur to you that this was important information to put into the question?

Answer (score 0):

**1st issue: the crash**
If you remove the deletion instruction the crash should vanish as `pop` returns the value and deletes the pointer from the end of the queue for you.

**2nd issue: memory leak**

You are not actually deleting data, just pointers so you are effectively orphaning data when you delete the pointers, leading to your memory leak.

If you can post some code I may be able to help more:)

Comment: @cppcoder an SSCCE is a little different from relevant code - by providing one, we can reproduce your error on our end and debug it more rapidly than on a forum waiting for your responses

Comment: But `pop` doesn't call `delete` on the pointer, it simply removes it from the underlying container.

Comment: Sorry yes, was answering hurriedly, what I mean is it is not removing data from memory, just deleting the pointer from the queue